# Corresponding graph: Forest <-> Tree, "???" <-> Polytree

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a specific term for a graph, that consists of Polytrees, like a Forest consists of Trees? Or can a Polytree be disconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=hLiUCveXsXEC&q=polyforest#v=snippet&q=polyforest&f=false) defines it as a polyforest. I imagine it's not a term that is used often because in applications the graph in question is generally connected.

See [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=bVHHZJgf56IC&q=polyforest#v=snippet&q=polyforest&f=false) also.